# merge and split the p:inputText column in in table jsf2.0

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0

Please give me idea how to design UI.

After clicking command button(MERGE BUTTON) or drag and drop the command button(MERGE BUTTON) to next row or any specific row ,then dropped(MERGE BUTTON dropped) row input text branch column get the MERGE BUTTON row branch value.
So pose if we try to click  or drag and drop the command button(MERGE BUTTON) in row1 to row2 , the row2 Branch input text is to get the first row Branch input text value. And for these two columns share the same value and these two columns make change to one column.
UI looks like below

ADD STUDENT button here

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 Student No         Student Name            Branch
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 input text1        input text2          input text3    MERGE BUTTON
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 input text1        input text2          input text3    MERGE BUTTON
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 input text1        input text2          input text3    MERGE BUTTON
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 input text1        input text2          input text3    MERGE BUTTON
---------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                            SAVE BUTTON Here
```

Here one branch have multiple students.
     After entering the first row details.If we try to add the next row student details,
     So pose second row student also need same branch then after clicking or drag and drop the the MERGE button
     in first row to second row then in second row  branch input text get the first row branch column value.
MERGE BUTTON is changed to SPLIT BUTTON.

After UI will look like

```
ADD STUDENT button here
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 Student No         Student Name            Branch
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 student1              name1                              SPLIT BUTTON 

                                            branch1       
 student2              name2                              SPLIT BUTTON

---------------------------------------------------------------------
 student3              name3                branch2       SPLIT BUTTON 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 student4              name4                branch3       SPLIT BUTTON 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                              SAVE BUTTON Here
```

When we try to click the SPLIT BUTTON in row 1 the branch column will show 
     input text box to change the Branch.
     After UI looks like below

ADD STUDENT button here

---

```
 Student No         Student Name            Branch
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 student1              name1                input text    MERGE BUTTON 
----------------------------------------------------------------------                                                 
 student2              name2                branch1       SPLIT BUTTON
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 student3              name3                branch2       SPLIT BUTTON
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 student4              name4                branch3       SPLIT BUTTON
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           SAVE BUTTON Here
```